# Getting Top 5 Results using ROWNUM in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

is there something wrong with my query? I use below to get the first 5 results ordered by AUDIT_ACTN then AUDIT_STAMP.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE_SAMPLE ORDER BY AUDIT_ACTN  
ASC,AUDIT_STAMP ASC)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 5
```

And I use this to check if I'm getting the correct rows.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_SAMPLE  ORDER BY 
AUDIT_ACTN,AUDIT_STAMP
```

The problem is the top 5 rows of the 2nd query is slightly different with the result of the 1st query. Only 3 rows are the same and with my observation the other 2 are the rownum1 & 2 of the 2nd query. I hope you understood my question I really need help.Thanks!

Comment: Do the columns AUDIT_ACTN, AUDIT_STAMP provide a unique ranking? If not then that might be your problem.

Comment: Some rows have exactly the same AUDIT_STAMP up to the seconds and i'm not sure if the AUDIT_STAMP(TIMESTAMP) differentiate each rows by milliseconds.

Comment: What is the actual issue? The two queries return different sets of rows? Or the two queries return the same set of rows but in a different order?

Comment: The two queries return partially different results. The first 2 rows are the same then the next two are different the last one exist in both results but in different position. That's the exact result :)

Answer (score 2):

I remember reading that `ORDER BY` would not be guaranteed with subqueries, but here is an alternative solution using `ROW_NUMBER` -- this includes the `ORDER BY` in it's `OVER` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT Field1, Field2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Field2,Field1) AS RN 
 FROM TABLE_SAMPLE 
 ) t 
WHERE RN <= 5
```

And here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c653d/1).

And here is some documentation about Oracle, subqueries, and ORDER BY:

http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.2.2/ref/rrefsqlj13658.html

> In subqueries, the ORDER BY clause is meaningless unless it is
>   accompanied by one or both of the result offset and fetch first
>   clauses or in conjunction with the ROW_NUMBER function, since there is
>   no guarantee that the order is retained in the outer result set. It is
>   permissible to combine ORDER BY on the outer query with ORDER BY in
>   subqueries.

Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately that gave same result.... i tried this `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE_SAMPLE ORDER BY AUDIT_ACTN ASC,AUDIT_STAMP ASC) WHERE ROWNUM IN (1,2,3,4,5)' and it gave the correct results however I don't how I can execute that since 5 is a parameter and it can be changed.

Comment: @user1173805 -- see my SQL Fiddle -- you cannot use ROW_NUMBER() with SELECT * -- you'll have to explicitly list your fields names.  Good luck.

Comment: It seems that the SQL Fiddle isn't working. I'm sorry it's my first time to use that. I don't know how to use it. Anyway, I found a way to get the result I want..I use this `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE_SAMPLE ORDER BY AUDIT_ACTN ASC,AUDIT_STAMP ASC) WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN 0 AND 5` that way I change 5 and 0 is always the default in any case. Thanks for the help I'll take a look at your post again and the documentations when I get time.

Comment: @user1173805 -- no problem, not sure why the Fiddle isn't working for you (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c653d/1) -- you do need to be careful about using ORDER BY in your subqueries as your RDBMS can alter that order due to indexes, and several other factors (even if its working now, doesn't guarantee it will always work).  Best of luck!

Comment: Really? now I'm nervous! LOL...If it's okay to you.. can you explain further how I can use the query you gave and how to use SQL Fiddle :)

Comment: @user1173805 -- No worries.  SQL Fiddle is just a tool to show you an example.  Assuming your table has 5 fields, you'll want to SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, AUDIT_ACTN, AUDIT_STAMP, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AUDIT_ACTN, AUDIT_STAMP) AS RN -- then wrap that up like I did above.  You cannot SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER... -- that's not allowed.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.. here's what I did `SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT AUDIT_STAMP,AUDIT_ACTN, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AUDIT_ACTN,AUDIT_STAMP) AS RN 
 FROM TBALE_SAMPLE )t  
WHERE RN <= 5` but the result is the same with the 1st query I gave in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:This query return top 5 record .

```
 SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT Field1, Field2, rank() OVER (ORDER BY Field1,Field2) AS rank
     FROM TABLE_SAMPLE 
     ) t 
    WHERE t.rank <= 5
```

Comment: +1 Even though this may return more than 5 records if `Field1,Field2` are not unique (It's better to get more than 5 records but a "correct" result)

Comment: ORDER BY is still needed in the main query to guarantee that the order of the results is the same as with `SELECT * FROM TABLE_SAMPLE ORDER BY Field1,Field2`.